# Selecting high bit rate video from master playlist .m3u8 to play video using AVPlayer

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, tvos

I have mater playlist .m3u8 that files contain's other index file of type .m3u8 now app requirement's is to play video of high bit rate video, is it possible to achieve this and play high bit rate video using AVPlayer(apple tvOS).

Master playlist contains following index files

## EXTM3U

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=378000,RESOLUTION=256x144,CODECS="avc1.42001e,mp4a.40.2"

someurl.m3u8

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2072000,RESOLUTION=480x270,CODECS="avc1.42001e,mp4a.40.2"

someurl.m3u8

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2671000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"

someurl.m3u8

Now according to requirement app needs to play below url from master play list.
ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2671000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
someurl.m3u8

Is it possible to achieve this using AVPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
player.currentItem?.preferredPeakBitRate = 2072000
```

only sets an upper bound on bitrate, so for example you could exclude the highest bitrate using this.

The thing is, AVFoundation will not choose a bitrate that is higher than the network connection's throughput, because that would result in choppy playback, which is not a sensible strategy.

That said, if you really  want to force playback of the highest bitrate asset, you could intercept the fetching of the outer m3u8 file and suppress the lower bitrate entries, or parse the file and play the highest bitrate URL directly with `AVPlayer`.

Comment: Hi Rhythmic I have used the same approach of setting  preferredPeakBitRate but I thing depending on bandwidth player is playing low quality video.
I was thinking about other solution which you provided parsing the file and playing the highest bitrate URL but I am facing issue in how to parse the file, can you provide any link or code for  parsing the above file.

Comment: There are some cocoapods that parse m3u8 files, e.g. https://github.com/alexsun/M3U8Paser

Comment: @RhythmicFistman And what if playlist have subtitle too in master. I fetched the resolution file and passed it but then subtitle was not available in characteristics. Have tried mutablerequest too but no success. Any help? Example

Comment: #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="FIL",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="Filipino",URI="layer06.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=334164,RESOLUTION=428x240,SUBTITLES="subs"
layer05.m3u8
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=334164,URI="iframe_layer05.m3u8"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=672686,RESOLUTION=640x360,SUBTITLES="subs"
layer04.m3u8
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=672686,URI="iframe_layer04.m3u8"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1046294,RESOLUTION=960x540,SUBTITLES="subs"
layer03.m3u8